# How to pipe to a file for a specific range of stream?

Tags: files

As a workaround of [some other problem of mine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362395/any-chances-to-read-a-btrfs-snapshot-as-a-file) I need to pipe to a stream to a file, but a specific part of it.

In brief, what I need to achieve is as follows:

**original case:**

```
mysource > mysource.img
# mysource.img is 500GB
```

**my intention:**

```
mysource | stream-take 0 100GB > mysource-0.img
# mysource-0.img is 100GB 
# 
# some times later, after processing above out file
rm mysource-0.img
mysource | stream-take 100GB 200GB > mysource-1.img
# mysource-1.img is 100GB 
...
```

**then, concatenate these files at remote location:**

```
cat mysource-* > mysource.img
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `dd` command:

```
mysource | dd bs=1M count=100K skip=0K iflag=fullblock of=mysource-0.img
# some times later, after processing above out file
rm mysource-0.img
mysource | dd bs=1M count=100K skip=100K iflag=fullblock of=mysource-1.img
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `split` command:

```
mysource | split --bytes 100G
```

See also: [How to split larger files into smaller parts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54579/how-to-split-larger-files-into-smaller-parts)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want to pass the parameters explicitly because "I have no such disk space" to hold all splits.